# Taking khula makes me sinful?

Tags: practical-islam

My husband is a mumma's boy he never provided for me as he was in a liberal family he wanted me to do job outside and do everything like a man does for his family as he is jobless most of the time he said himself that he married me for money and he doesn't love me and kept on criticising me for my looks i tried to do everything to save our marriage but he doesn't want to change he is not even a practicing Muslim he even beats me and leaves me alone when I need him the most his family even treats him as a 31 yr old boy who keeps on sharing each thing to his mother and sister they even told me to end this relationship everytime so when he punched me seval times for stupid thing i took khula.He never apologizes i always say sorry even if he is wrong.people say he is a Narcissist.

Am i sinful will i not smell the scent of paradise???

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Nobody can be sinful just because he/she takes his/her right that was given him/her by Allah.

Answer (score 0):

My dear sister, the difficult circumstances you are going through require support and assistance. Islam encourages compassion, affection and cooperation between spouses, and never condones abuse or violence. Allah ﷻ said:

> “And live with them kindly” — Qur'an 4:19

The Prophet ﷺ, emphasized the good treatment of wives in his saying:

> “The best of you is the best to his family, and I am the best to my
> family.”

You are not guilty of striving to preserve your dignity and safety. Islam honors women and gives them the right to live with dignity and respect. If the husband does not fulfill his marital rights, the wife has the right to request khula. Feeling guilty because you decided to walk away from the marriage that hurt you is not fair to yourself.

Paradise is not denied to anyone because of his pursuit of justice and preservation of his dignity. Paradise is inherited by those who fear Allah ﷻ and do good deeds, and Allah ﷻ knows every person’s circumstances and intentions.

I advise you to contact a specialized family counselor or a mufti or an imam who has an understanding and awareness of the Shari'ah and family situations to provide you with support and advice. Always remember that Allah ﷻ is with those who are patient and that He does not waste the reward of those who do good deeds.